# $location.search() not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

**Update2:**

$location just for ng.
so *`$location.search`* is ng's search
it parse url from mark like **#** or **#!** .

but *`$window.location`* handle the brower url

in my question, first url's ng search is empty
and second url's ng search is {code & state}

is it right?

**Update1:**

i found the `*$window.location*` got the right data.
is `*$location*` override the all things?

**Question**
i use **angular-ui-router** in my project. and i want to get search string from url,
like this: `http://localhost:8080/?code=123456&state=auth#/api/oauth2_authorize`
in *app.config*, i set:

```
$stateProvider.state("oauth2_authorize", {
            url: "/api/oauth2_authorize?code&state",
            template: "",
            controller: function($location) {
                       var search = $location.search();
            }
        })
```

i think the search will be `{ code : 123456; state:auth}` but no.
i try to change the url to : `http://localhost:8080/#/api/oauth2_authorize?code=123456&state=auth`
and it work.

somebody could tell me why? the **html5mode** is *false*.
i check the angularjs's document, and **$location**'s sample show that, i can get the search string from **both** url.
and i try to use $urlRouterProvider , but it still empty.

what can i do?

Comment: What about `$stateParams` ?

Comment: @PSL sorry, it also empty at the first url. second url work.

Comment: I guess it should work when you enable HTML5model true. can't you enable it?

Comment: @MYN... thanks for your help, but it not work....

Answer (score 1):

Because, if you set  `html5mode` to `false`, all your urls need to have `#`. Even if in your url state you dont have `#` .

For that reason 
`http://localhost:8080/?code=123456&state=auth#/api/oauth2_authorize` doesn't work and 
`http://localhost:8080/#/api/oauth2_authorize?code=123456&state=auth` 
it does.

Check [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) for `$location` and urls

Comment: @GeminiYellow np, are you fine then ? your questions is answered?

Comment: i try set html5mode to true, but ui.router 's state can not route the url. some thing need to add?

Comment: @GeminiYellow what urls are you using ? give me an example.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/?code=123456&state=auth#/api/oauth2_authorize is the url receive from server.

Comment: hello, could you tell me how to get search object in not html5model ?in ui.router.

Comment: @GeminiYellow your url is wrong, it should be `/api/oauth2_authorize?code=123456&state=auth` if you want to match it with your defined state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69418/discussion-between-geminiyellow-and-levi).

Answer (score 0):

I guess something wrong with AngularJs version you are using.
Which version are you using?
refer following link suggest the same issue and fix with HTML5Mode=true
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/6198

Or just go through following pages, may be helpful to fix your issue.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5964

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4607